# How to set the ImageSource path with BitmapImage in code-behind

Tags: visual-studio-2010, imagebrush

I'm trying to a Background image which is in my VS2010 project's Images folder.  I have read the documentation and I tried several ways including following but can't get it to work:

```
        ImageBrush bg2 = new ImageBrush();
        bg2.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/FooApplication1;component/Images/bg1.png"));

        ImageBrush bg1 = new ImageBrush();
        bg1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "/FooApplication;component/Images/bg1.png"));
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the URI should look something like this:

```
"pack://application:,,,/Images/bg1.png"
```

Did you read [this article on URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)?